# Term::ReadKey, "Strg+D" and STDIN

Tags: perl, stdin, eof, readkey

When I type after `Enter a string:` for example `a`, `b`, `c` and then two times <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> I get an endless loop which doesn't halt on `ReadKey` and which I can not stop with the <kbd>Q</kbd> key?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;
use Term::ReadKey;

while( 1 ) {
    my $c;
    say "Press the \"q\" key to quit.";
    print "Press the \"e\" key to enter a string: ";
    {
        $|++;
        Term::ReadKey::ReadMode 'ultra-raw';
        $c = ReadKey 0;
        Term::ReadKey::ReadMode 'restore';        
    }
    exit if ord( $c ) == 3; # Control C
    last if $c eq 'q'; 
    if ( $c eq 'e' ) {
        print "\nEnter a string: ";
        my $string = <>;
        if ( not defined $string ) {
            say "Undefined";
        }
        else {
            chomp $string;
            say "You entered |$string|";
        }
    }
    say "Still running";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you type the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (EOT), your programm will only receive NUL-bytes. And an infinity of them. Unfortunately you have an unconditional read in an infinite loop. Either you change that (e.g. give the user a lesson if he types something other than `q` or `e` and exit if he didn't get it after the third try), or you implement control characters correctly. Your module strips all control characters from the input *before* you even get it, but it provides the neccessary hooks. I urge you to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> as well (it only works when a line is expected, not when a char is being read).

Also, why not compare the input characters with string equality? `$c eq "q"` reads nicer.

Comment: How could I catch the `Ctrl`-`D`?

Answer (score 0):

The only line that will terminate your loop is this one:

```perl
last if ord( $c ) == 113;
```

So, the only way to escape the loop is to enter 'q' when the prompt asks you to enter 'e'.

Presumably you want an appropriately placed `last` inside your `if` statement, so that ctrl-d and/or any text will terminate.